# Css-sprite menu not working in ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-sprites

Why doesn't Internet Explorer render this .css sprite menu i made?
Could someone shed some light for me as i am unable to find any error in the code.
**Html:**

```
<div class="menu">
     <ul class="nav">
         <li class="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element2"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element3"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element4"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element5"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element6"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="element7"><a href="#"></a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Css for wrappers and links:**

```
    .menu{
     height:350px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     float:left;
     width:150px;  
    }

/*Menu*/
.nav{
 background:url("menusprite.png");
 height:350px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.nav li{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
 top:0;
}
.nav li, .nav a{
 height:50px;
 display:block;
}
```

**And example css for a:link and :hover:**

```
.home{ 
        left:0;
     height:50px;
}
.home a:hover{
     background:url("menusprite.png")-150px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css should look more like:

```
.home a:hover{
     background:transparent url("menusprite.png") no-repeat scroll -150px 0;
}
```

There were two things wrong in your css:

1. **url(...)-150px**: You need to have a space between the attributes in the css properties
2. **-150px 0 no-repeat**: background-repeat (and background-attachment) should come before background-position in the shorthand

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Well it seems lazy css is the problem:)

Comment: glad to help. some browsers are more forgiving than others. Of course, sometimes their tolerance of errors can make debugging harder.